# Javascript connect to websocket

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, websocket

Following up form my last question -

```
var socket;
if ("WebSocket" in window)
  {
     alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");
     // Let us open a web socket
   socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:10001");
  }

socket.onopen() = function(){
    alert("Connection Opened");
}


socket.onmessage() = function(msg){
    alert(msg);
}
```

I can connect to the server with telnet but I can't seem to connect using Javascript, why is this?

Comment: `socket.onopen() = function(){` should be `socket.onopen = function(){`

Comment: ah yes thank you, I just changed it, but even then I still don't seem to connect whilst telnet can :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because WebSocket is not a normal, general-purpose socket. It requires the server on the remote end to conform to a very specific handshake defined by [the WebSocket protocol](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-socket-protocol/). If your server does not implement this protocol, WebSocket cannot connect to it.

Additionally, as Rocket points out, your code is currently attempting to call `socket.onopen()` and assign a value to the function call. Lose the parentheses.

Comment: I don't think protocol is a problem as I am using the standard PHP sockets. But i have found that it may be connecting, as once the javscript runs I can't connect via telnet as the connection is refused. But with socket.onopen , it still doesn't notify me that it has connected

Comment: If you have not **specifically** implemented the WebSocket handshake, WebSocket cannot connect to it. If you aren't sure, you probably haven't.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am totally mistaken, I have just read what you gave me and totally understand. Luckily I have just found an example which implements this. Many thanks